# Is there any method by which we can access the local storage of any website by our chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-extension

I am trying to build my 1st chrome extension for which I need it to be automatically logged in when we install that by accessing the local storage of our website if a user is logged in to the website

Comment: A Chrome extension can access the local storage of an **open** website through a content script.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension that does almost same thing [Storage Area Explorer](https://github.com/jusio/storage-area-explorer)